# Convert 'object' column to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I currently have the following dataframe (with seven days, one day displayed below). Hours run from 01:00 to 24:00. How do I convert the HourEnding column to datetime format and combine it with the date_time column (which is already in datetime format)?

```
    HourEnding  LMP date_time
0   01:00   165.27  2021-02-20
1   02:00   155.89  2021-02-20
2   03:00   154.50  2021-02-20
3   04:00   153.44  2021-02-20
4   05:00   210.15  2021-02-20
5   06:00   298.90  2021-02-20
6   07:00   152.71  2021-02-20
7   08:00   204.61  2021-02-20
8   09:00   155.77  2021-02-20
9   10:00   90.64   2021-02-20
10  11:00   57.17   2021-02-20
11  12:00   43.74   2021-02-20
12  13:00   33.42   2021-02-20
13  14:00   5.05    2021-02-20
14  15:00   1.43    2021-02-20
15  16:00   0.99    2021-02-20
16  17:00   0.94    2021-02-20
17  18:00   12.13   2021-02-20
18  19:00   18.90   2021-02-20
19  20:00   19.04   2021-02-20
20  21:00   16.42   2021-02-20
21  22:00   14.47   2021-02-20
22  23:00   44.55   2021-02-20
23  24:00   40.51   2021-02-20
```

So far I've tried

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['HourEnding'])
```

but that seems to fail because of the 24:00.
Similarly

```
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta('HourEnding', 'h', errors = 'coerce')
```

yields a column of NaTs.

Comment: Does the hour 24 corresponds to midnight of the next day ?

Comment: It corresponds to minute of that day - so HourEnding 01:00 is 1AM, HourEnding 24:00 is midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert both columns to strings, then join them into a new 'datetime' column, and finally convert the 'datetime' column to datetime.

EDIT: To deal with the 1-24 hour problem, build a function to split the string and subtract 1 from each of the hours and then join:

```
def subtract_hour(t):
    t = t.split(':')
    t[0] = str(int(t[0]) - 1)
    if len(t[0]) < 2:
        t[0] = '0' + t[0]
    return ':'.join(t)
```

Then you can apply this to your hour column (e.g., `df['hour'] = df['hour'].apply(subtract_hour)`) and proceed with joining columns and then parsing using `pd.to_datetime`.

EDIT 2: You just want to change '24' to '00', my bad.

```
def mod_midnight(t):
    t = t.split(':')
    if t[0] == '24':
        t[0] = '00'
    return ':'.join(t)
```

Comment: EDIT 2 is the way to go I think. This way all the values from 1 to 23 won't be shifted by one hour.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I misunderstood the question initially.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the comments, hour 24 corresponds to midnight of the same day. I would simply start by replacing "24" by "00" :

```
df['HourEnding'] = df.HourEnding.str.replace('24:00', '00:00')
```

Then, convert `date_time` to string :

```
df['date_time'] = df.date_time.astype(str)
```

Create a new column that concatenates `date_time` and `HourEnding` :

```
df['date_and_hour'] = df.date_time + " " + df.HourEnding
df['date_and_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_and_hour)
```

Which gives you this :

```
>>> df
   HourEnding     LMP   date_time       date_and_hour
0       01:00  165.27  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 01:00:00
1       02:00  155.89  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 02:00:00
2       03:00  154.50  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 03:00:00
3       04:00  153.44  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 04:00:00
4       05:00  210.15  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 05:00:00
5       06:00  298.90  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 06:00:00
6       07:00  152.71  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 07:00:00
7       08:00  204.61  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 08:00:00
8       09:00  155.77  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 09:00:00
9       10:00   90.64  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 10:00:00
10      11:00   57.17  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 11:00:00
11      12:00   43.74  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 12:00:00
12      13:00   33.42  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 13:00:00
13      14:00    5.05  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 14:00:00
14      15:00    1.43  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 15:00:00
15      16:00    0.99  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 16:00:00
16      17:00    0.94  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 17:00:00
17      18:00   12.13  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 18:00:00
18      19:00   18.90  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 19:00:00
19      20:00   19.04  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 20:00:00
20      21:00   16.42  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 21:00:00
21      22:00   14.47  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 22:00:00
22      23:00   44.55  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 23:00:00
23      00:00   40.51  2021-02-20 2021-02-20 00:00:00

>>> df.dtypes
HourEnding               object
LMP                     float64
date_time                object
date_and_hour    datetime64[ns]
```